# Flexible filter in AngularJS Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I had a repetitive HTML code, with very small changes).This peace of HTML simply shows JSON objects in a table as follows:

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Employee</th>
    <th>Start date</th>
    <th>End date</th>
    <th>status</th>
    <th>Select</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="oneRecord in currentEmployeeData.RecordsOfJSONS|filter : {status: 'pending'}">
    <td>{{oneRecord.employee.personalInfo.firstName + ' ' + oneRecord.employee.personalInfo.lastName}}</td>
    <td>{{oneRecord.startDate}}</td>
    <td>{{oneRecord.endDate}}</td>
    <td>{{oneRecord.status}}</td>
    <td>
        <div ng-if="oneRecord.status === 'created' ">
            <cs-checkbox ng-model="oneRecord"
                         ng-click="collectRequests(oneRecord)"></cs-checkbox>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

There are two important aspects in here:

1) Filtering records : some times I want to filter by the 'status' field of the JSON objects. As it is visible in this example, and sometimes by other fields for example 'startDate'.

2) The last column of the table shows a checkbox base on a value of the 'status' field. In this case if 'status === created' then checkbox is shown. In other situations checkbox should show up base on another value of status field.

Since the table was being repeated with almost same pattern, I decided to implement it with Directive possibility of AngularJS as follow:

```
m.directive("csHolidayTable", [function () {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                JSONrecords: "=",
                filtervalue: "=",
                filterparameter : "=",
                checkboxcondition: "="
            },

            template:'<table class="cs-table-01">' +
            '<thead> <tr> +
            '<th>Employee</th>' +
            '<th>Start date</th>' +
            '<th>End date</th>' +
            '<th>Status</th>' +
            '<th>Select</th>' +
            ' </tr> </thead> ' +
            '<tbody> <tr ng-repeat="oneRecord in holidays|filter : { filterparameter : filtervalue }">' +
            '<td>{{oneRecord.employee.personalInfo.firstName + " " + oneRecord.employee.personalInfo.lastName}}</td> ' +
            '<td>{{oneRecord.startDate}}</td> ' +
            '<td>{{oneRecord.endDate}}</td>' +
            '<td>{{oneRecord.status}}</td> '+
            '<td> <div ng-if="oneRecord.status === checkboxcondition"><cs-checkbox ng-model="oneRecord" ng-click="collectRequests(oneRecord)"></cs-checkbox> </div> </td> </tr></tbody></table>',

            controller : function ($scope) {
                //this part implements checkbox functionality.
                var firstVal = null;
                var secondVal = null;
                var counter = 0;
                multipleRequests = [];
                $scope.collectRequests = function (oneRequest) {
                    counter = counter + 1;
                    if (counter == 1) {
                        firstVal = oneRequest;
                    } else if (counter == 2) {
                        secondVal = oneRequest;
                        if (secondVal === true) {
                            multipleRequests.push(firstVal);
                            counter = 0;
                        } else {
                            multipleRequests.pop(firstVal);
                            counter = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }]);
```

And then in my HTML code I simply used this custom HTML tag as follow:

```
   <cs-holiday-table JSONrecords="currentEmployeeData.RecordsOfJSONS" checkboxcondition = "'pending'" filterparameter="'status'" filtervalue="'created'"></cs-holiday-table>
```

or somewhere else:

```
   <cs-holiday-table JSONrecords="currentEmployeeData.RecordsOfJSONS" checkboxcondition = "'created'" filterparameter="'startDate'" filtervalue="'2015-01-02'"></cs-holiday-table>
```

Now the problem : Checkboxes are shown correctly, Probably because it is only a ng-if condition in HTML template part of directive.
But filter does not work. And I do not understand Why.
I also used this line directive defenition, and still no result:

```
<tr ng-repeat="oneRecord in holidays|filter : { {{filterparameter}} : filtervalue }">
```

Anybody has idea how can I implement this type of 'flexible filtering' ? 
that both JSON field and its desired value are passed from HTML to directive. 
I would be grateful in case of detailed solution.

Comment: What was the name of your filter?

Comment: What do you mean by 'name of filter' ? It varies case by case. As I explained depend on a situation I want to have freedom to choose any of the fields available in the JSON object. This the problem.If I use a 'fixed' field in HTML template of Directive definition , it works.

Comment: for example this one works:<tr ng-repeat="oneRecord in holidays|filter : { status: filtervalue }">

Comment: @Makoto Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because in AngularJS "filterparameter" won't be overwritten with "startDate" or "status". <strike>Instead of that you can try to use 2 parameters in your filter: one for the name and another you the value.</strike>

<strike>By the way, you can also use your browsers developer tools to add a breakpoint in your filter to evaluate the values which are passed. This way you can check if filterparameter is overwritten or not.</strike>

*edited:*
you pass 2 values to your directive and use it in ng-repeat. change your directive to a single attribute like 'filterconditions' and set an json format as follow `<cs-holiday-table JSONrecords="currentEmployeeData.RecordsOfJSONS" checkboxcondition = "'created'" filterconditions="{ 'startDate' : '2015-01-02' }"></cs-holiday-table>`

and use in your directive as: 
`<tr ng-repeat="oneRecord in holidays | filter : filterconditions">`

this way you are also able to set conditions based on multiple values like 
{'status': 'created', 'startDate':'2015-01-02'} or on single value like {'status': 'created' } or { 'startDate':'2015-01-02'}

https://embed.plnkr.co/nyLl6w9iBwgWDvTUbN7p/

I hope this helps.

Comment: Using two filters with hardcoded JSON fields like "startDate" or "status" does not solve the problem. The problem is sending filterparameter and desired value of it , from HTML code. Otherwise I need to keep adding hard-coded fields every time I want to use different JSON field. Even though I also tried to use two filters and it does not work. Next answer illustrate trying to use two filters.

Comment: I think the next code example will show what I actually mean: https://embed.plnkr.co/YU9yHcblJds1bT2VKdDZ/

Comment: I am thinking to complicated. I have updated my answer

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use tow filters in directive and none of them worked successfully.

```
<tr ng-repeat="oneRecord in holidays|filter : { status : filtervalue}|filter : { startDate : filtervalue}">
```

or this one:

```
<tr ng-repeat="oneRecord in holidays|filter : { status : filtervalue}|{ startDate : filtervalue}">
```

or

```
<tr ng-repeat="oneRecord in holidays|filter : { status : filtervalue| startDate : filtervalue}">
```